Microservice connection error to mongo database on container
I have a client that uses a small service that we provide.
They did an update and and now they are starting to see the following error:
"{\n \"error\": \"server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Single, Servers: [{ Addr: mongo:27017, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() : dial tcp: lookup mongo: Temporary failure in name resolution }, ] }\",\n \"message\": \"MONGODB INSERT ERROR\",\n \"zipID\": \"f7f44bbe-2fd5-4b96-8749-19b2b30f7ce6\"\n}\n"


Usually they never let me access their servers but they would like to solve the issue.
Is this a mongo issue or a general linux name resolution error?

It’s difficult to provide a definitive answer without knowing more about your infrastructure, but I have a couple of suggestions.
It could be a general Linux name resolution error:
To check this, I suggest verifying the general connectivity between the service and MongoDB. You can try pinging the MongoDB DNS name from the container or VM to see if the name resolution is working. You can also test connectivity without DNS using tools like ping, nc, or telnet, which will help us determine whether network connectivity exists.
You can refer to this answer for more details: Linux command line error message: Temporary failure in name resolution
Additionally, it could be related to the application itself:
I suggest checking what exactly was updated (perhaps a network library), and try reproducing and fixing the issue. You might find some useful information here: Temporary failure in name resolution,mongo-sec:27017

It turns out it was both. But the problem was fixed by rebooting host machine.
